# Pytorch: choosing columns from a 3d tensor, according to indices tensor

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I have a 3D tensor `M` of dimensions `[BxLxD]` and a 1D tensor `idx` of dimensions `[B,1]` that contains column indices in the range `(0, L-1)`. I want to create a 2D tensor `N` of dimensions `[BxD]` such that `N[i,j] = M[i, idx[i], j]`. How can this be done efficiently?

Example:

```
B,L,D = 2,4,2

M = torch.rand(B,L,D)

>

tensor([[[0.0612, 0.7385],
         [0.7675, 0.3444],
         [0.9129, 0.7601],
         [0.0567, 0.5602]],

        [[0.5450, 0.3749],
         [0.4212, 0.9243],
         [0.1965, 0.9654],
         [0.7230, 0.6295]]])


idx = torch.randint(0, L, size = (B,))

>

tensor([3, 0])

N = get_N(M, idx)

Expected output:

>

tensor([[0.0567, 0.5602], 
       [0.5450, 0.3749]])
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: if you find my answer useful, please consider accept it. and do tell me what's wrong if you find it doesn't work. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import torch

B,L,D = 2,4,2

def get_N(M, idx):
    return M[torch.arange(B), idx, :].squeeze()

M = torch.tensor([[[0.0612, 0.7385],
                   [0.7675, 0.3444],
                   [0.9129, 0.7601],
                   [0.0567, 0.5602]],

                   [[0.5450, 0.3749],
                   [0.4212, 0.9243],
                   [0.1965, 0.9654],
                   [0.7230, 0.6295]]])
idx = torch.tensor([3,0])
N = get_N(M, idx)
print(N)
```

result:

```
tensor([[0.0567, 0.5602],
        [0.5450, 0.3749]])
```

slice along two dimensions.